# Which object exactly support asterisk(or double asterick) for positional argument(or keyward argument) in python? Any criterion?

Tags: python-3.x, asterisk

I have used `*` or `**` for passing arguments to a function in `Python2`, not in question, usually with `list`, `set` and `dictionary`.

```
def func(a, b, c):
   pass

l = ['a', 'b', 'c']
func(*l)

d = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b', 'c': 'c'}
func(**d)
```

However, in `Python3`, There appear the new objects replacing `list` with or something, for example, `dict_keys`, `dict_values`, `range`, `map` and so on.

While I have migrated my `Python2` code to `Python3`, I need to decide whether the new objects could support the operation which former object in `Python2` did so that If not, I should change the code using like type-cast to origin type, for instance `list(dict_keys)`, or something.

```
d = {'a': 'a', 'b': 'b'}
print(list(d.keys())[0])    # type-case to use list-index
```

For Iterating I could figure out by the way below.

```
import collections
isinstance(dict_keys, collections.Iterable)
isinstance(dict_values, collections.Iterable)
isinstance(map, collections.Iterable)
isinstance(range, collections.Iterable)
```

It looks clear to distinguish if the new object is iterable or not but like the title of the question, how about `asterisk` operation for `position/keyword argument`?

Up to now, all objects replaced `list` with support `asterisk` operation as my testing but I need clear criterion not testing by hand.

I have tried a few way but there is no common criterion.

1. they are all `Iterable` class?

   - no, `Iterable` `generator` doesn't support.
2. they are all `Iterator` class?

   - no, `Iterator` `generator` doesn't support.
3. they are all `Container` class?

   - no `map` class is not `Container`
4. they all have a common `superclass` class?

   - no there is no common superclass(tested with `Class.mro()`)

How could I know if the object support `asterisk`(`*`, `**`) operation for `position/keyword argument`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each iterable "supports" starred expression; even genrators and maps do. However, that "an object supports `*`"  is a misleading term, because the star means "unpack my interable and pass each element in order to the parameteres of an interface". Hence, the `*` operator supports iterables.

And this is maybe where your problem comes in: the iterables you use with `*` have to have as many elements as the interface has parameters. See for example the following snippets:

```
# a function that takes three args
def fun(a, b, c):
    return a, b, c

# a dict of some arbitrary vals:
d  = {'x':10, 'y':20, 'z':30}            # 3 elements
d2 = {'x':10, 'y':20, 'z':30, 't':0}     # 4 elements
```

You can pass `d` to fun in many ways:

```
fun(*d)             # valid
fun(*d.keys())      # valid
fun(*d.values())    # valid
```

You cannot, however, pass `d2` to `fun` since it has more elements then
`fun` takes arguments:

```
fun(*d2)    # invalid
```

You can also pass maps to `fun` using stared expression. But remeber, the result of `map` has to have as many arguments as `fun` takes arguments.

```
def sq(x):
    return x**2

sq_vals = map(sq, *d.values())

fun(*sq_vals)    # Result (100, 400, 900)
```

The same holds for generators if it produces as many elements as your function takes arguments:

```
def genx():
    for i in range(3):
        yield i

fun(*genx())    # Result: (0, 1, 2)
```

In order to check whether you can unpack an iterable into a function's interface using starred expression, you need to check if your iterable has the same number of elements as your function takes arguments.

If you want make your function safe against different length of arguments, you could, for example, try redefine you function the following way:

```
# this version of fun takes min. 3 arguments:
fun2(a, b, c, *args):
    return a, b, c

fun2(*range(10))    # valid
fun(*range(10))     # TypeError
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, I seemed to do miss-test with generator.

Answer (score 0):

> The single asterisk form ( *args ) is used to pass a non-keyworded,
>   variable- length argument list, and the double asterisk form is used
>   to pass a  keyworded, variable-length argument list

[args and kwargs explained](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRh9uA2prYAhUKC8AKHRsdBDMQFgh1MA4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3&usg=AOvVaw1KH0i_Ipb5y4LKLM6hSvEN)[also this one](https://www.google.com.gh/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=15&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjRh9uA2prYAhUKC8AKHRsdBDMQFgh1MA4&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.digitalocean.com%2Fcommunity%2Ftutorials%2Fhow-to-use-args-and-kwargs-in-python-3&usg=AOvVaw1KH0i_Ipb5y4LKLM6hSvEN)

Comment: I know what they are, I just want to know which objects support the operation and what is the criterion for if the object support or not.